# How to convert char 10/2013 to use the filter >=

Tags: sql

I have a problem with a part of my script:

```
where BillingMonth = '10/2013'
```

Which works fine, but I need to change it to

```
where BillingMonth >= '10/2013'
```

which does not work because `BilingMonth` is datatype `char(7)` so I can not use `>=`.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the format so the month is YYYY-MM.  That would make simple comparison easy.

Here is the idea on how to fix this:

```
where concat(right(BillingMonth, 4), left(BillingMonth, 2)) >= '201312'
```

Unfortunately, this syntax varies by database.  The above works in MySQL, for instance.  The equivalent in SQL Server would be:

```
where right(BillingMonth, 4) + left(BillingMonth, 2) >= '201312'
```

And some databases don't support `left()` and `right()`, using `substr()` or `substring()` instead.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the format, but this is in one of my source systems, not in mine. So I guess I can contact the admin, but just in case it is good to have a workaround, so thanks a lot!